# SQL Server Developer edition on Ubuntu: Allowing remote connections

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I've got SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition up and running on my Linux VM. I'd like to remotely connect to that SQL Server instance from my Windows development PC.

All of the information I can find online basically revolves around configuring a Windows based SQL Server to allow remote connections and then connecting into it from Linux, which I need the opposite of. I'd like to write some Python code on my development machine to interact with this db.

I use Dbeaver as an interface tool, and I've ran the following:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 0;
```

and

```
RECONFIGURE;
```

But I'm really not sure what else to do from here, I've never configured anything like this before.

When looking at `netstat -tulpn` I can see SQL Server listening on `127.0.0.1:1434` along with some other ports, as well as `0.0.0.0` and even `:::1433`.

But utilizing `sqlcmd -S my_server_ip,1434 -Usa` on Windows is running into:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Any tips on setting this up? Possibly a firewall issue, or are there configuration steps I'm not thinking of?

Comment: tcp/1434 is the [Diagnostic Connection for Database Administrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators). That's not the port you're looking for, because it only allows a single login and only from members of the SysAdmins group and only on the localhost address.

Comment: For some reason it sounds like you've disabled the standard TCP/IP port of the mssql service on Ubuntu. You'll need to use the `mssql-conf` tool to reconfigure it, or maybe edit the `/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf` file directly. See [Configure SQL Server on Linux with the mssql-conf tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf) for more information.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You legend, tried it again on 1433 and I connected just fine. Thank you sir. I'll have to do more digging into this.